# Can't import a pdf file to a .tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I recently start building a portfolio website using React JS and TypeScript. I'm having a difficulty in importing a pdf file from my images to the resume.tsx file in my project folder.
[image]
The error indicates that: "Cannot find module '../images/resume.pdf' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)"

I used the exact same code on my normal React JS file (.jsx) and it worked without any errors.

[image]

I'm a total beginner in using Typescript and I'm building the website to learn TypeScript. Can someone tell me what did I miss on my code?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the typings for the PDF.

Best way to do it is to create a file in your root called `types.d.ts` and paste in the PDF type, which is `declare module '*.pdf';`

Then create a `tsconfig.json` file also in the root and add the following

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["types.d.ts"]
    },
}
```

Comment: How can a PDF file have typings? It's a binary blob...

Comment: It's now throwing an error that says: The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "eslint": "5.12.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

Comment: @dai it's a declaration for the file extension that isn't natively supported https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8021

Comment: @jeffrey that looks like a different issue, potential solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788469/start-react-app-fail-on-vscode-by-eslint-version